# FileNotFound when trying to find heavy hitters in a text file of 1,000,000 ints

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist, try-catch

I am trying to find heavy hitters in a text file of **1,000,000** ints.

For some reason when I run it never finds the file.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong so any help would be the best.

I believe my code for the entire  program is correct except for the fact it wont find the file.

```
public class HH1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 100;
        int count = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        File file = null;
        Scanner s = null;

        try {
            file = new File("IT179ProjectData.txt");
            s = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //Taking values from text file and inserting into an array list 
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            intList.add(s.nextInt());

        }

        //Creates an array from the array list
        Object[] array = intList.toArray();

        //Sorts the array
        Arrays.sort(array);

        int n = array.length;
        int hh = n / k;
        System.out.println("The heavy hitters from the IT179ProjectData are:");

        //Traverses the Array
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (count == hh && array[i] == array[i++]) {
                System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
                count++;
            } else if (count != hh && array[i] == array[i++]) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Please help!

EDIT!!!!! Below is the error message of my code:

/NetBeansProjects/IT179.Proj/IT179ProjectData.txt

```
Error file not found
java.io.FileNotFoundException: IT179ProjectData.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at it179.proj.HH1.main(HH1.java:35)
/home/ADILSTU/bsdwork/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: What's the error? For future reference, posting code with "it doesn't work" has a specific close reason on this site if you do not post the **full error** (stack trace) then the question will be fairly promptly closed...

Comment: Where is `IT179ProjectData.txt`? Where are you running this from?

Comment: P.S finding the top `100` numbers by reading all `1,000,000` into RAM and sorting them is possibly the worst way to solve this problem. Whilst it will work for "small" numbers of numbers, if you get to `1,000,000,000` and more you'll begin to have issues. Furthermore, `Scanner` is by far the slowest way to read data, it's really designed for user input which is so slow that the slowness of `Scanner` is immaterial.

Comment: This question lacks the error-message. In general: this sort of error-handling is really bad. No matter what error occurs, this program will always print the same error-message. You should atleast use the error-message given by the `Exception`. And while directly terminating seems a good option in this case, calling `System.exit(0)` is in general a rather bad idea. And exit-code when an error occurs would be 1, not 0.

Comment: Please use "e.printStackTrace();" (or some logger etc.) in your catch block otherwise you swallow the real exception message.

Comment: Finally, swallowing `Exception` and printing `Error` is a disciplinable offence in many software houses - if you want to be a programmer stop doing this **right now**. if you cannot handle an `Exception` is a sensible manner; don't `catch`  it to begin with.

Comment: @yshavit i took the file from the internet and saved it as a text file then dragged it into the source packages

Comment: @BoristheSpider yea I know but I was specified to do it this way because I will be making an online data stream version as well using a hash map this is basically an "offline" version and I do not have to take each int one by one

Comment: @BenDworkin If it's in the source files, then you don't want to use File to get it -- you want to look it up as a resource (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html to start your research, but there's lots out there). That's especially important if you eventually package your project up in a jar, because then your IT179ProjectData.txt won't be available as a separate file on the disk -- it's just rolled up into the jar -- so there's no way for a `File` to get to it.

Comment: Re-asked by the OP [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189637/filenotfoundexception-problems-using-netbeans)

Answer (score 5):

When you are trying to load a file and you are getting a FileNotFoundException that it is not found / does not exist, the problem is usually that the directory that Java is looking in is not the directory you are expecting it to look in. After this line:

`file = new File("IT179ProjectData.txt");`

Try calling

`System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath())`;

I'm sure you'll discover what's going wrong doing this.

Note also that you can discover the default directory Java by using `System.getProperty("user.dir");`

Comment: Re-asked by the OP [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189637/filenotfoundexception-problems-using-netbeans)